# cpuminer - what command line tools are required?

Tags: mining-pools, client, miner-configuration

I'm trying to run cpuminer on my Mac, though cpuminer requires a lot of command line tools - such as curl, libidn, etc. What are all of the tools required, and what is the minimum version of each I must obtain (e.g. curl 6)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compiled it on Linux. These are the dependencies once compiled :

```
$ readelf -d minerd

Dynamic section at offset 0x1c178 contains 22 entries:
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libcurl.so.4]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libpthread.so.0]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
...
```

That's only `libcurl` and `glibc`. Since `glibc` is just a standard C library, and Mac probably has its own equivalent, you can ignore that one. The only runtime requirement is `libcurl`.

Judging by the source code the minimum required version of libcurl is 7.10.1. You'll also need `yasm` for 64-bit SSE2 code generation. And of course a C compiler that can handle C99.